# Find in a dynamic pythonic way the minimum elements in a partially ordered set

Tags: python, algorithm, math

Let Os be a partially ordered set, and given any two objects O1 and O2 in Os, F(O1,O2) will return 1 if O1 is bigger than O2, -1 if O1 is smaller than O2, 2 if they are incomparable, and 0 if O1 is equal to O2.

I need to find the subset Mn of elements is Os that are the minimum. That is for each A in Mn, and for each B in Os, F(A,B) is never equal to 1.

It is not hard to do, but I am convinced it could be done in a more pythonic way.

The fast and dirty way is:

```
def GetMinOs(Os):
    Mn=set([])
    NotMn=set([])
    for O1 in Os:
       for O2 in Os:
           rel=f(O1,O2)
           if rel==1:       NotMn|=set([O1])
           elif rel==-1:    NotMn|=set([O2])
    Mn=Os-NotMn
    return Mn
```

In particular I am not happy with the fact that I am essentially going through all the elements N^2 times. I wonder if there could be a dynamic way. 
By "dynamic" I don't mean merely fast, but also such that once something is discovered being not a possible in the minimum, maybe it could be taken off. And doing all this in a *pythonic*, elegant way

Comment: this more of an algorithm question than an implementation question

Comment: Search for a paper with the title "A simple sub-quadratic algorithm for computing the subset partial order." I think it gives a simple solution to your problem. BTW, how large are your sets?

Comment: Os is a subset of a set which can have thousands of elements. Usually it will have much less elements, but I need to call this multiple time, at least twice, every time I add an element. So it is paramount that it is optimal. I just downloaded the paper, btw. Are you the author?

Comment: no, i'm far from being the author :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetMinOs2` below, "dynamically" removes elements which are known to be non-minimal. It uses a list `Ol` which starts with all the elements of `Os`. 
A "pointer" index  `l` points to the "end" of the list `Ol`. When a non-minimal element is found, its position is swapped with the value in `Ol[l]` and the pointer `l` is decremented so the effective length of `Ol` is shrunk.
Doing so removes non-minimal elements, so you don't check them again.

`GetMinOs2` assumes `f` has the normal properties of a comparison function: transitivity, commutativity, etc.

In the test code below, with a dreamt-up `f`, my timeit run shows about a 54x improvement in speed:

```
def f(O1,O2):
    if O1%4==3 or O2%4==3: return 2
    return cmp(O1,O2)

def GetMinOs(Os):
    Mn=set([])
    NotMn=set([])
    for O1 in Os:
       for O2 in Os:
           rel=f(O1,O2)
           if rel==1:       NotMn|=set([O1])
           elif rel==-1:    NotMn|=set([O2])
    Mn=Os-NotMn
    return Mn

def GetMinOs2(Os):
    Ol=list(Os)
    l=len(Ol)
    i=0
    j=1
    while i<l:
        while j<l:
            rel=f(Ol[i],Ol[j])
            if rel==1:
                l-=1
                Ol[i]=Ol[l]
                j=i+1
                break
            elif rel==-1:
                l-=1
                Ol[j]=Ol[l]
            else:
                j+=1
        else:
            i+=1
            j=i+1
    return set(Ol[:l])


Os=set(range(1000))

if __name__=='__main__':
    answer=GetMinOs(Os)
    result=GetMinOs2(Os)
    assert answer==result
```

The timeit results are:

```
% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.GetMinOs2(test.Os)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 22.7 msec per loop
% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.GetMinOs(test.Os)'
10 loops, best of 3: 1.23 sec per loop
```

PS. Please be warned: I haven't thoroughly checked the algorithm in GetMinOs2, but I think the general idea is right. I've put a little test at the end of the script which shows it works at least on the sample data `set(range(1000))`.

Comment: doesn't seem to make much of a difference O()-wise

Comment: Hi unutbu, thanks. I wrote back dynamic on the question, because I don't mean merely a "fast" way, but a way in which I don't even start a cycle on an element that cannot be. As such I am thinking of an algorithm that is dynamic in its nature. And I do agree with hop that your code does not make a huge difference. On the one side there is one less call on f, but on the other checking of O2 in NotMn might cost the same. Plus it's done for each element. So all in all it might even be slower!

Comment: H unutbu, np about the edit :-). Thanks for testing your solution, thanks for taking the time. The problems in the two functions: f(O1,O2) and "O2 in NotMn" ("O2 in NotMn"). You are essentially having to check if O1 is in NotMn every time, to get an improvement by not having to run f(O1,O2). Unfortunately it is not said which of the two take longer. In your example you had a set for which "O2 in NotMn" was much faster than f(O1,O2), so it made sense. But it might not always be so. Especially as NotMn grows!

Comment: wow, it works (+1)! Amazing. I tried also using the f:  def f(O1,O2): if O1%3==O2%3: return cmp(O1,O2); else return 2. Now, how do we pythonise it? As it is right now it looks like C. Thanks, Pietro

Comment: @Pietro: I have no idea how to make it more pythonic. I hardly know what the term "pythonic" means. Readability could be improved by giving the variables more descriptive names, and by following PEP8. At this point, I'm more concerned that the algorithm works as desired. It needs unit testing.